# Change public IP address of EC2 instance to Elastic IP Address

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to assign Elastic IP Address  to my instance without changing the public IP address?, i need to Transforms my public IP address to be Elastic IP Address

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible. You can access your instance with Both Elastic IP as well as Public IP Address. But remember when your EC2 instance restart at that time its public IP may get change so people preferring to use Elastic IP Address.

Hope this Helps !

Comment: I have a public IP address and have all my DNS configured to use that address.  I have an elastic IP address that is not associated with an instance.  So can I associate my elastic ip address with the EC2 instance,  then configure my DNS to use the elastic ip?  And during propagation both ip addresses will make it to the server (so that I will not be down for 48 hours)?

Comment: So can I associate my elastic ip address with the EC2 instance, then configure my DNS to use the elastic ip? - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Using Elastic Network Interfaces it is possible if you started the instance in a VPC. You can assign the Elastic IP to an Elastic Network Interface which you can then attach to the EC2 instance. EC2 instances in VPC can have multiple ENI. If you assign an EIP directly to the EC2 instance (classic or VPC) then the public IP changes to the EIP.

> When you associate an EIP with an instance, the instance's current
>   public IP address is released to the EC2-Classic public IP address
>   pool. If you disassociate an EIP from the instance, the instance is
>   automatically assigned a new public IP address within a few minutes.
>   In addition, stopping the instance also disassociates the EIP from it.

from: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html